# Listing all values of an object's property from JSON file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to list all 'languages' from a JSON file into a `<li>` using the rest countries API (https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all) that looks like this (example country Malta)

```
languages: {
eng: "English",
mlt: "Maltese"
},
```

My code

```
filteredCountries.map(country =>
          <div key={country.cca2}>
            <h1>{country.name.common}</h1>
            <>Capital: {country.capital}</><br/>
            <>Population: {country.population.toLocaleString()}</>
            <h3>Languages</h3>
            <ul>
              {Object.keys(country.languages).map(lang => { 
              <li key={lang.name}>{lang.name}</li>
            }
              )}
            </ul>
            <img src={country.flags.png} alt='Country Flag'/>
          </div>
```

I am able to pull the country name, capital, population and flag but unable to list the languages in an efficient manner since every country has a varied number of languages. Using `Object.keys` doesn't provide errors but it doesn't display what I want. I tried using `country.languages.map` but I get the error of `TypeError: country.languages.map is not a function` I was able to get the country name and capital using `country.name.cca2` and `country.capital` respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `country.languages[lang]` inside the `Object.keys(country.languages).map()`

Also because you are using lambda notation, you need to leave out the curly braces `{` and `}` after the `=>`.

```
{Object.keys(country.languages).map(lang =>
  <li key={lang}>{country.languages[lang]}</li>
)}
```

Or, if you want the curlies, then the code inside the curly braces needs to use the `return` keyword:

```
{Object.keys(country.languages).map(lang =>
  {
    return <li key={lang}>{country.languages[lang]}</li>
  }
)}
```

Comment: Peter's answer looks correct, are you sure you're doing `country.languages[lang]`?

Comment: It was correct, I'm not sure what I did wrong but I was able to fix it without using curly braces in the map method.

Comment: Indeed, I did not pay much attention to the braces, amended my answer, it should be correct now.